# What's a quick test to see if an $n \times n$ matrix is diagonal and/or proporitional to the identity matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

As the title indicates, I want to test whether an $n \times n$ matrix (numeric, symbolic,..) is diagonal and/or proportional to the $n \times n$ identity matrix. I, of course, can test whether the $n^2-n$ individual off-diagonal entries are zero--but that's, it would seem, is inefficient.

Comment: Something like `Norm[(# - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[#]]) &[mat], 1] == 0`?

Comment: Seems to work, thanks!

Comment: There's a built-in function DiagonalMatrixQ.

Comment: you can use `Statistics\`Library\`DiagonalMatrixQ`. Run `?*\`*DiagonalMatrixQ` can get this function.

Comment: It is not that easy. DiagonalMatrixQ ais nice but insufficient, there is the built-in function DiagonalizableMatrixQ. DiagonalizableMatrixQ checks, the given matrix is diagonizable. Matrices are in mathematics in general in relation classes. One class of interest is the relation class of diagonalizable matrixes to which the in diagonal form under consideration is a sub relational class. DiagonalizableMatrixQ in the Mathematica help offers many  answers of your question. There info for J. J. is in limbo in the paragraph Properties and Relations of it.

Comment: @user2432923 Paul asked for a check for _diagonal_ matrices, not for _diagonalizable_ ones.

Comment: I would strongly encourage to use `DiagonalMatrix`; there is a chance that there is an internal flag for diagonal matrices (as e.g. for symmetric ones) and if the flag is already set, `DiagonalMatrixQ` just has to read it off.

Comment: If you already know that the matrix is diagonal and want to check whether it is proportional to the identity matrix, check whether the minimum entry of the diagonal is  substantially smaller than the maximum, e.g., with `{min,max} = MinMax@Abs@Diagonal@matrix; min>= (1.-$MachineEpsilon) max`.